# .NETCore Application terminating due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, exception, raspberry-pi, .net-core

So,

I'm using a Raspberry Pi model 3b and i have successfully got .NetCore v2.0.1 running on it. I have been able to build the CoreIOT Hello World project and ran it without problem on my Pi now i have some custom hardware i have created using the GPIO board and the only way i could think to use it in .NETCore was to use the FileSystem method `/sys/class/gpio` I have built a very small app

https://github.com/barkermn01/CanReader

There is not much in there but for some reason when i run the app all i get is a message saying `Proccess is terminating due to StackOverflowException` I'm not sure what is causing it there is nothing in there too big i don't think just basic file system reading.

The only thing i can think of is it does not like the infinite loops

From: https://github.com/barkermn01/CanReader/blob/master/Program.cs

```
while (!exiting)
{
    Console.Write("\rCurrent State " + state);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "exit")
    {
        watcher.Stop();
        exiting = true;
    }
}
```

and From: https://github.com/barkermn01/CanReader/blob/master/GPIOWatcher.cs

```
public void watch()
{
    GPIO.Value val = Gpio.ReadValue();
    while (val != OldValue)
    {
        val = Gpio.ReadValue();
        if (Delegate != null)
        {
            Delegate.DynamicInvoke();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the [property getter of `GPIO.FullPath`](https://github.com/barkermn01/CanReader/blob/f62dadadfc109fb096601ecf165abfb97835b585/RaspberryPi/GPIO.cs#L83) which accesses itself:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Generates the full path for the Filesystem mappings for this GPIO pin
    /// </summary>
    public string FullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Path + "/" + this.FullPath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hate it when it's something so simple and i wonder why Visual Studios did not pick that up you would expect it to point out a self reference in a property.

Comment: I have changed it but i can't test until i get home so will test tonight and let you know.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly :) now just got to work out why it's able to write to one file and not to others :)